# jquery show hide form fileds using next and previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i have a form with 100s question in it..and checkbox or radio button as a option to answer the questions..

```
 <b style="font-weight:bold">1.How long have you been working in field of Programming?</b><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="Less than 2 years" style="cursor:pointer">
  <span style="display: inline-block;font-size: 13px;position: relative;top: -2.5px;">Less than 2 years</span>

  <input type="radio" name="1" value="3-5 years" style="cursor:pointer">
  <span style="display: inline-block;font-size: 13px;position: relative;top: -2.5px;">3-5 years</span>

  <input type="radio" name="1" value="6-10 years" style="cursor:pointer">
  <span style="display: inline-block;font-size: 13px;position: relative;top: -2.5px;">6-10 years</span>

  <input type="radio" name="1" value="11-15 years" style="cursor:pointer">
  <span style="display: inline-block;font-size: 13px;position: relative;top: -2.5px;">11-15 years</span>
```

the above `html` is my first question out of `100` questions....so for this i have decided..to create a `next` and `previous` button for `10` questions at a time on a screen?

any suggestion or help would be a great help?.. thanks in advance..

Comment: `<b style="font-weight:bold">` Isn't that redundant? Also, where's the JavaScript you've tried?

Comment: right sir.. i have created a css for this..!

Comment: I must tell you that you can put your CSS into a stylesheet, making your HTML code readable and less redundant. I hope you only decided to do it this way because you have not heard of stylesheets :).

Comment: @kapa Sir.. i am not good in css and jquery.. but i have written this: b{font-weight:bold;} and its works perfect..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the most simple approach I could get.

**HTML:**
Add `div`'s for pages *(1st page has an extra `active` class)*

```
<div class="page active">
    <!-- A set of questions go here -->
</div>

<div class="page">
    <!-- Another set of questions go here -->
</div>
...
```

**CSS:**

```
.page { display: none; }
.active { display: inherit; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#prev").on("click", function(){
    if($(".page.active").index() > 0)
        $(".page.active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
});
$("#next").on("click", function(){
    if($(".page.active").index() < $(".page").length-1)
        $(".page.active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
});
```

And its done!

Fiddle with this example here: **http://jsfiddle.net/V8LCL/**

Comment: @786 sorry, I've forgot to check that ... I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/V8LCL/1/ it's working now ...

Comment: Sir..thank you very much this is what i am looking for..thanks a lot sir...i found the solution now..

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try my best given your small sample, but it seems to me you are very far away from being able to generalize the code to a page approach. I'll explain why

**Brute approach**

If you don't want to change anything I would say for you to write your 100 questions on the DOM like you have in your sample and create a section for each block of 10:

```
<section class="section-1" ... > </section>
```

Then in your javascript code you can have the current active page, let's say you start with 1:

```
var visiblePageIndex = 1
```

A next button would increment the page by 1 and a back button would decrement the visible page by 1, obviously taking into account the limits, 1 <= page <= 10.

Now for the show and hide, you need to make the `display` setting of the `section` to be lets say `inline-block` for the visible page index, and `none` for the all the others. You can do this in two ways:

1. In the same event where you process the `next` and `back` you can use jQuery to query all sections that contain the number of the visible index (http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/).
2. Having a css selector with the same functionality (http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

I would prefer the second. This should do the trick but obviously this is maintenance heavy, and it doesn't adjust automatically.

**A more dynamic approach**

I will try to illustrate the key points of this approach, the code will have to written by you, or if you get me a sample, I can help you get there.

You will need to store your questions and possible answers in a data structure, hopefully in a JSON or XML (bah) file, or if you can't be bothered simply inline in your JS block.

This will allow you to iterate over that structure with javascript and append to the DOM the number of questions you want to see each time. A click on `next` or `prev` will just change the index from where you start and draw the respective group.

You can save the answers in the same structure so when the user navigates back he will see his/her selections.

The pros of this option are:

- Dynamically adjusts for the size of questions
- You can customise how many questions are shown with a simple variable change
- it's more lightweight, since you don't have to load a massive DOM.
- You practice your JS a bit.

I hope this helps, there are a ton of possible solutions for this. This is just a couple of them, but I would definitely try to go number 2 or anything similar instead of hacking it (option 1).

Comment: thank you very much sir..for your important time..i found the solutions by `Toni Almeida Sir` ...